# How can I find the PPPoE password configured in Airport

Tags: airport

I'm connecting to internet via PPPoE with a AirPort Express. Now I want to replace AirPort with another router, but I don't remember the password of my PPPoE account. So I'm wondering how can I extract the password from the provisioned AirPort Express.

Answer (score 1):

If your PPPoE is provided by your ISP, so contact you ISP's help is short way than try to extract the account info from AE's settings.